# How do I write Serilog events to a .NET collection?

Tags: serilog

I want to write Serilog `Warning` events to a .NET collection so they can be included in a report to the user. How do I [configure the static `Log.Logger`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) to write to something like a `static List<string<>` ?

I saw the [Rx Observer in the list of provided sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks#observers-rx), this was the only one that seemed to readily make .NET objects available or is there an obvious alternative that I missed?

Alternatively, is this a dumb way to do it - is there a better way to collect just `Warning` events to massage into a user-facing report?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class CollectionSink : ILogEventSink {
    public ICollection<LogEvent> Events { get; } = new ConcurrentBag<LogEvent>();

    public void Emit(LogEvent le) {
        Events.Add(le);
    }
}

var col = new CollectionSink();
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Sink(col, LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .CreateLogger();

// read col.Events....
```

Not sure this one will typecheck but this is essentially how I've done it a few times.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` & `ConcurrentBag<T>` are unrelated but this got me on the right track. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I found the following implementations useful as references:

1. [CollectionSink from the Serilog Timings tests](https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-timings/blob/c6f7313c45bdf72f6dc11da1c12e717ffb5250bd/test/SerilogTimings.Tests/Support/CollectionSink.cs)
2. [InMemorySink from Serilog.Sinks.InMemory](https://github.com/sandermvanvliet/SerilogSinksInMemory/blob/cc7312ca98c120859a65bc8b76bb44cf9fe95a73/src/Serilog.Sinks.InMemory/InMemorySink.cs)